# IOS7 Table view cell touching delay with cell property UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview, custom-cell

I want to make a custom table view cell like this.

- If `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault`, there's no delay when touching but my title label's background color disappeared.
- If `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`, title label's background color is fine, but there's touching delay to present modal VC. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "touching delay"? That property is purely cosmetic and does not change the behavior of the cell.

Comment: @Dima The time modal VC comes to front is really long when cell touched.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like this, under the `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    switch (cell.selectionStyle) {

        case UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone:

            // your are making an delay with NSTimer
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(trigger:) userInfo:cell repeats:NO];
            break;

        case UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault:

            // changing your labels color
            [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

- (void)trigger:(id)timer {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[timer userInfo];

    // _yourModelController is your destination controller
    [self presentViewController:_yourModelController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

but personally I wont advice to do a decision making based on `selectionStyle` property.

Comment: @user3627556 if it's helpful and if you think the answer is correct then don't forget to mark it as a right answer which help other users.

Comment: I use UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() function to make a UIImage as  the label's background view and it works. I've googled something about IOS7 tableViewCell inheritance, there's a new view named UITableViewCellScrollView fathers cell's contentView. I think it has something to do with the problem. Still thank you, but I don't think it's the best answer. Sorry!